# Using Gravity Forms Merge Tag into Wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to generate a Gravity Forms number field value into word format. I would like to use Wordpress shortcode for that, but I am not able to add the gravity forms merge tag (number field) into the shortcode.

I found a solution here to generate wordpress shortcode which converts a number into word just putting a static number on the shortcode number value
[Is there an easy way to convert a number to a word with wordpress via shortcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008880/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-word-with-wordpress-via-shortcode)

But my goel is to put the Merge tag instead of static number so the number of the shortcode dynamically pulls from the gravity forms field number:

Current Wordpress shortcode: 
[convertNumber number="2222"]

This works fine at the moment to convert the number into word.

I want to make it work like below: 
[convertNumber number="{Donation Amount:15}"]

Where "{Donation Amount:15}" is the gravity forms merge tag which generates the number value which user input on that particular form field.

I have used the following function to produce the above wordpress shortcode with static number.

```
function number_to_word($atts, $content){
    include('class.numberformatter.php');
    // let's fetch all of the arguments of the shortcode
    $atts = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'number' => '0',
        ), $atts );
    $number = $atts['number'];
    $number_formatter = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
    $converted = $number_formatter->format($number);
    return $converted;
}
add_shortcode( 'convertNumber', 'number_to_word' );
```

Now I want to generate Gravity forms merge tag value within the shortcode so it converts that number into word.

Your help is highly appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The tricky bit here is identifying from which entry the value of the merge tag should be retrieved. [Gravity Post Post Content Merge Tags](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-post-content-merge-tags/) solves this issue by allowing you to pass a token parameter to the page and then you can use any merge tag in your post content.

Comment: Okay is this possible to use a merge tag inside a shortcode like this: 
[convertNumber number="{Donation Amount:15}"]

Ofcourse this particular merge tag {Donation Amount:15} generates a whole number only. I am confused is the given post merge tags by gravitywiz is the right solution. Can you please elaborate a bit more the process?

Comment: Post Content Merge Tags (PCMT) will allow you to use the merge tag inside the shortcode attribute just like you described: [convertNumber number="{Donation Amount:15}"]

The only additional requirement from PCMT is that you identify which entry the merge tag should fetch the value from. You would do this via the "eid" parameter in the URL. There are some other options if your use-case doesn't allow for the the query string parameter.